# Join from 2 tables using foregin key MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

hello I am trying to join a table Classes & Employee together by using the foreign key "Employee_Id" from the C table to get the first and last name from the E table

```
SELECT     class_id, 
           subject_name, 
           classes.employee_id 
FROM       schooladmindb.classes 
INNER JOIN schooladmindb.employee 
ON 
where      classes.employee_id = employee.employee_id;
```

Im unsure of the statement I would have to use to just gain "First_Name" & "Last Name" From the E table which keeping the C table data intact

Comment: What is the question? Does Your query work? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statment is wrong because you dont need the `WHERE` to join both tables

Check **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** sintaxis

```
SELECT     class_id, 
           subject_name, 
           classes.employee_id 
FROM       schooladmindb.classes 
INNER JOIN schooladmindb.employee 
ON         classes.employee_id = employee.employee_id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the First name & Last name of an employee using the employee_ID using a statement like this? and have it alongside class id etcin a grid view. that's the problem i'm having EDIT  I was being stupid and not adding "employee.FirstName" in my select statement before the FROM tag. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question. Try to include your db schema, some sample data and desire result. Also try to use `ALIAS` instead of table name to make it easy read the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply add first name and last name along with other fields like

```
SELECT     class_id, 
           subject_name, 
           employ_FirstName, // Column in your employee table
           employ_LastName,
           classes.employee_id 
FROM       schooladmindb.classes 
INNER JOIN schooladmindb.employee 
ON         classes.employee_id = employee.employee_id;
```